# Migration: Column already exists error when creating new tables

Tags: laravel

I did a search on possible resolutions to this issue and I couldn't find anything when creating a new table in `Laravel 7`. But, I am getting a Column already exists error when running `php artisan migrate` while creating new tables. The column that is in the error is `contract_type_id`.

Here is a snip of the migration file:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('contract_data', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('contract_type_id');
        $table->integer('customer_id');
        $table->date('start_date');
        $table->date('end_date');
        $table->integer('product1_id');
        $table->integer('product2_id');
        $table->integer('product3_id');
        $table->integer('product4_id');
        $table->integer('product5_id');
        $table->integer('product1_gallons');
        $table->integer('product2_gallons');
        $table->integer('product3_gallons');
        $table->integer('product4_gallons');
        $table->integer('product5_gallons');
        $table->decimal('product1_price', 9,6 );
        $table->decimal('product2_price', 9,6 );
        $table->decimal('product3_price', 9,6 );
        $table->decimal('product4_price', 9,6 );
        $table->decimal('product5_price', 9,6 );
        $table->integer('fuel_contract_number');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('contract_data', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('contract_type_id')->constrained('contract_type');
        $table->foreignId('customer_id')->constrained('customer_details');
        $table->foreignId('product1_id')->constrained('product_details');
        $table->foreignId('product2_id')->constrained('product_details');
        $table->foreignId('product3_id')->constrained('product_details');
        $table->foreignId('product4_id')->constrained('product_details');
        $table->foreignId('product5_id')->constrained('product_details');
        $table->foreignId('fuel_contract_number')->constrained('fuel_contracts');
    });
}
```

Comment: Error aside, take another look at your data structure... Anytime you have multiple of the same columns, with only a difference in the number is an opportunity to correctly normalize your data. You should have a pivot table for `products` instead of `product{x}_` columns.

Comment: @TimLewis thank you for the feedback. where would i find documentation on working with pivot tables?

Comment: It's a pretty complicated subject, but you'll need to do some research into Database Normalization (Normal Forms, 1st Normal, 3rd Normal, etc etc). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization summarizes it, but there's a lot more to it.

Comment: As for the error, I'm pretty sure one of the functions `foreignId` or `constrained` also creates the column, but you're already creating it in the first block of the migration. Read over the documentation for them here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I'm brand new to Laravel and i found their documentation on relationships, but not sure if thats what i need to do. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Yeah, database engineering and design stretches way beyond just Laravel; the same concepts apply to all frameworks and languages; if you don't have a good database design, you'll have trouble working with the framework to it's fullest.

Comment: On your last comment, i wasn't sure if that was the case. They don't really explain that if its a foreign key that you should not included it in the initial create.

Comment: Yeah, it's an either or; you either define the column and set the index in two separate lines: `$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');` and `$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');`, or you do it in a single line: `$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();`. In your code, you have both, which is why you're getting that error.

Comment: I applied your fix, now i'm getting a foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed error. Might this be, because the other tables aren't created yet?

Comment: Yes, likely. If you haven't created and run the migration for `products`, then you'll get that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **foreignId** method is an alias for **unsignedBigInteger** while the **constrained** method will use convention to determine the table and column name being **referenced** 
So you are making `contract_type_id` field twice.

> `$table->foreignId('contract_type_id')->constrained('contract_type');` **alias of** `$table->unsignedBigInteger('contract_type_id');` **&**  `$table->foreign('contract_type_id')->references('id')->on('contract_type);`

So in your second migration it would be :

```
$table->foreign('contract_type_id')->references('id')->on('contract_type);
```

Instead of :

```
$table->foreignId('contract_type_id')->constrained('contract_type');
```

Also you need to use **Unsigned Big Integer**, as :

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('contract_type_id');
```

Not,

```
$table->integer('contract_type_id');
```

Because **Laravel 5.8** Added `unsignedBigInteger` as defaults for foreign key, also for **Laravel 6** and **7**

Comment: I ended up creating a model, adjusting the Schema like listed above, and then ran a migration. I did this for each table i was creating and i was able to get all the tables made. It felt like a clunky process, but i'm sure i was doing it wrong. Either way all the tables are created.