# Foreign key is incorrectly formated - Laravel 7 migration

Tags: php, laravel

This is my first Laravel project and I'm having a hard time defining a table with a many-to-many relationship.

I want to create a table which will 'link' each teacher from a table with one or more domains they are interested in. Each domain can be linked to multiple teachers.

I approached the idea this way:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class teacherAndTheirDomain extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('teacherAndTheirDomain', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedInteger('teacher_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('domain_id');
            
            $table->foreign('teacher_id')
                  ->references('id')->on('teachers')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('domain_id')
                  ->references('id')->on('domains')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('teacherAndTheirDomain');
    }
}
```

but I get "Can't create table, foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed".

Can anybody explain to me what I'm doing wrong, please, and why am I getting this error?

Thanks :)

Comment: Try with `$table->unsignedBigInteger(...);`

Comment: @DimitriMostrey it worked. You can add that as an answer, I will accept it asap. Can you explain why did it worked, though, please?

Comment: Foreign key needs to be of the exact same type as the column it's referencing. You most likely used `->id()` on your other table which is UNSIGNED BIGINT https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations You could have just used `$table->foreignId(..);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Migration: Column already exists error when creating new tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63058885/migration-column-already-exists-error-when-creating-new-tables)

Comment: @brombeer yes. That was the answer. thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foreign key constraints must be of the same type as the referencing table. As explained on 'Conditions and Restrictions' on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Since Laravel 7, the default is set to `$table->bigIncrements('id');` instead of `$table->increments('id');`. Hence, the foreign key should be of the same type:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('teacher_id');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('domain_id');
```

The rest of the migration file stays the same.

**ps**: you don't need to use big integers as the table `id` type. In most circumstances, falling back on the *old* `$table->increments('id');` will be just fine. Once you made a choice, try to be consistent in all other migrations to avoid future conflicts in your application.